Depth First Search with a stack (specifically a la CLRS with parent and timestamp attributes)
Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein (CLRS) give (section 22.3) a recursion-based implementation of DFS that not only adds parent data u.parent to each node u along the way but also timestamp fields u.d and u.f which are supposed to respectively indicate the time when u is first visited and the time when we completely finish processing u including all its neighbors, their neighbors, etc.  The algorithm runs in O(|V| + |E|).
DFS(G)
    for each vertex u in G.V
        u.color = WHITE
        u.parent = NIL
    time = 0
    for each vertext u in G.V
        if u.color == WHITE
            DFS-VISIT(G, u)

DFS-VISIT(G, u)
    time = time + 1
    u.d = time
    ui.color = GRAY
    for each v in G.Adj[u]
        if v.color == WHITE
            v.parent = u
            DFS-VISIT(G, v)
    u.color = BLACK
    time = time + 1
    u.f = time

Exercise 22.3-7 asks for a non-recursive algorithm to compute the DFS that uses a stack.
My initial response was to do something like this, but as this issue mentions, there is some question about the ability to keep this O(|V| + |E|)
Other approaches here and here are clearly O(|V| + |E|), but do not set the parent attributes in a way that results in a depth-first-tree (see this issue).  (Furthermore the first one sets v.f too soon, ie. before the neighbors of v are explored.)
Any speculation on what CLRS might have had in mind here?
EDIT:  Ok, I think I see how we can make the first approach work in O(|V|+|E|) by using a dictionary of stacks to keep track of the next white neighbor in an efficient way (see comment here).  I guess I'm still curious if folks can think of simpler solutions.

Did it in Python so I can test. DFS and DFS_VISIT are just Python versions of the original.
My DFS_VISIT_2 is a non-recursive replacement for the latter. I represent each visit with a generator iterator. Instead of recursive calls, they yield the node-to-visit back to the main loop, which creates a visit for it and puts it onto the stack.
My DFS_VISIT_3 is another non-recursive replacement, but instead of a stack of generator iterators, I just use a stack of pairs of a node and an iterator over its adjacent nodes.
The rest of the code is a test, running DFS with all implementations on the same random graph and comparing the results, i.e., all the node attributes written. They're equal.
WHITE, GRAY, BLACK = 'WHITE', 'GRAY', 'BLACK'
NIL = 'NIL'

def DFS(G):
    for u in G.V:
        u.color = WHITE
        u.parent = NIL
    global time
    time = 0
    for u in G.V:
        if u.color == WHITE:
            DFS_VISIT(G, u)

def DFS_VISIT(G, u):
    global time
    time = time + 1
    u.d = time
    u.color = GRAY
    for v in G.Adj[u]:
        if v.color == WHITE:
            v.parent = u
            DFS_VISIT(G, v)
    u.color = BLACK
    time = time + 1
    u.f = time


def DFS_VISIT_2(G, u):
    def visit(u):
        global time
        time = time + 1
        u.d = time
        u.color = GRAY
        for v in G.Adj[u]:
            if v.color == WHITE:
                v.parent = u
                yield v
        u.color = BLACK
        time = time + 1
        u.f = time
    visits = [visit(u)]
    while visits:
        for child in visits[-1]:
            visits.append(visit(child))
            break
        else:
            visits.pop()


def DFS_VISIT_3(G, u):
    def enter(u):
        global time
        time = time + 1
        u.d = time
        u.color = GRAY
        return u, iter(G.Adj[u])
    def leave(u):
        u.color = BLACK
        global time
        time = time + 1
        u.f = time
    visits = [enter(u)]
    while visits:
        u, adj = visits[-1]
        for v in adj:
            if v.color == WHITE:
                v.parent = u
                visits.append(enter(v))
            break
        else:
            leave(u)
            visits.pop()

import random
class Graph:
    pass
class Node(int):
    pass
expect = None
for DFS_VISIT in DFS_VISIT, DFS_VISIT_2, DFS_VISIT_3:
    random.seed(0)
    G = Graph()
    G.V = [Node(_) for _ in range(100)]
    G.Adj = {u: random.sample(G.V, 10) for u in G.V}
    DFS(G)
    result = [(u, u.color, u.parent, u.d, u.f) for u in G.V]
    if expect is None:
        expect = result
    else:
        print(DFS_VISIT.__name__, result == expect)
for node in expect:
    print(node)

Output, showing whether my implementations produced the expected results, and then the expected results (Attempt This Online!:
DFS_VISIT_2 True
DFS_VISIT_3 True
(0, 'BLACK', 'NIL', 1, 200)
(1, 'BLACK', 32, 99, 100)
(2, 'BLACK', 34, 82, 97)
(3, 'BLACK', 70, 9, 192)
(4, 'BLACK', 30, 42, 159)
(5, 'BLACK', 54, 23, 178)
(6, 'BLACK', 41, 61, 138)
(7, 'BLACK', 45, 18, 183)
(8, 'BLACK', 19, 52, 147)
(9, 'BLACK', 72, 49, 150)
(10, 'BLACK', 7, 19, 182)
(11, 'BLACK', 86, 57, 142)
(12, 'BLACK', 2, 87, 96)
(13, 'BLACK', 69, 59, 140)
(14, 'BLACK', 74, 6, 195)
(15, 'BLACK', 33, 21, 180)
(16, 'BLACK', 26, 39, 162)
(17, 'BLACK', 91, 45, 154)
(18, 'BLACK', 50, 76, 117)
(19, 'BLACK', 40, 51, 148)
(20, 'BLACK', 93, 78, 115)
(21, 'BLACK', 47, 47, 152)
(22, 'BLACK', 83, 32, 169)
(23, 'BLACK', 81, 67, 130)
(24, 'BLACK', 66, 15, 186)
(25, 'BLACK', 20, 107, 114)
(26, 'BLACK', 38, 38, 163)
(27, 'BLACK', 49, 3, 198)
(28, 'BLACK', 6, 62, 137)
(29, 'BLACK', 57, 89, 90)
(30, 'BLACK', 77, 41, 160)
(31, 'BLACK', 14, 7, 194)
(32, 'BLACK', 34, 98, 103)
(33, 'BLACK', 10, 20, 181)
(34, 'BLACK', 98, 81, 104)
(35, 'BLACK', 87, 13, 188)
(36, 'BLACK', 60, 11, 190)
(37, 'BLACK', 75, 30, 171)
(38, 'BLACK', 94, 37, 164)
(39, 'BLACK', 68, 84, 85)
(40, 'BLACK', 9, 50, 149)
(41, 'BLACK', 13, 60, 139)
(42, 'BLACK', 8, 53, 146)
(43, 'BLACK', 90, 25, 176)
(44, 'BLACK', 63, 133, 134)
(45, 'BLACK', 71, 17, 184)
(46, 'BLACK', 97, 111, 112)
(47, 'BLACK', 17, 46, 153)
(48, 'BLACK', 53, 55, 144)
(49, 'BLACK', 0, 2, 199)
(50, 'BLACK', 88, 75, 118)
(51, 'BLACK', 28, 63, 136)
(52, 'BLACK', 23, 68, 127)
(53, 'BLACK', 42, 54, 145)
(54, 'BLACK', 15, 22, 179)
(55, 'BLACK', 99, 72, 123)
(56, 'BLACK', 88, 119, 120)
(57, 'BLACK', 12, 88, 93)
(58, 'BLACK', 62, 35, 166)
(59, 'BLACK', 20, 79, 106)
(60, 'BLACK', 3, 10, 191)
(61, 'BLACK', 4, 43, 156)
(62, 'BLACK', 67, 34, 167)
(63, 'BLACK', 51, 64, 135)
(64, 'BLACK', 95, 70, 125)
(65, 'BLACK', 23, 128, 129)
(66, 'BLACK', 35, 14, 187)
(67, 'BLACK', 22, 33, 168)
(68, 'BLACK', 2, 83, 86)
(69, 'BLACK', 11, 58, 141)
(70, 'BLACK', 31, 8, 193)
(71, 'BLACK', 24, 16, 185)
(72, 'BLACK', 21, 48, 151)
(73, 'BLACK', 55, 73, 122)
(74, 'BLACK', 76, 5, 196)
(75, 'BLACK', 79, 29, 172)
(76, 'BLACK', 27, 4, 197)
(77, 'BLACK', 16, 40, 161)
(78, 'BLACK', 32, 101, 102)
(79, 'BLACK', 96, 28, 173)
(80, 'BLACK', 63, 65, 132)
(81, 'BLACK', 80, 66, 131)
(82, 'BLACK', 12, 94, 95)
(83, 'BLACK', 37, 31, 170)
(84, 'BLACK', 57, 91, 92)
(85, 'BLACK', 97, 109, 110)
(86, 'BLACK', 48, 56, 143)
(87, 'BLACK', 36, 12, 189)
(88, 'BLACK', 73, 74, 121)
(89, 'BLACK', 43, 26, 175)
(90, 'BLACK', 5, 24, 177)
(91, 'BLACK', 61, 44, 155)
(92, 'BLACK', 4, 157, 158)
(93, 'BLACK', 18, 77, 116)
(94, 'BLACK', 58, 36, 165)
(95, 'BLACK', 52, 69, 126)
(96, 'BLACK', 89, 27, 174)
(97, 'BLACK', 25, 108, 113)
(98, 'BLACK', 59, 80, 105)
(99, 'BLACK', 64, 71, 124)


Cool.   Your iterators play the role of the ("pop-able") data structure that I hand-waved at this comment https://github.com/walkccc/CLRS/issues/329#issuecomment-2480810421.
Still wonder what CLRS had in mind.  But these are good.  Have an upvote.

@tarski I suspect they do mean something like this. I.e., with some way to store the progress of their for each v in G.Adj[u] loop. If G.Adj[u] for example is an array that can be accessed with indices, then instead of an iterator you can store an index. I think I did that as well, but the code got longer and I didn't like it. (And I looove iterators.)
